# How to pass values dynamicallly from one processor to another processor using apache nifi

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-nifi

i want pass one processor result as input to another  processor using apache NiFi.

I am geeting values from mysql using ExecuteSQL processor .i want pass this result dynamically  to  SelectHiveQL Processor in apache nifi.

Answer (score 2):

[ExecuteSQL](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL/index.html) outputs a result set as Avro. If you would like to process each row individually, you can use [SplitAvro](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.avro.SplitAvro/index.html) then [ConvertAvroToJson](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.avro.ConvertAvroToJSON/index.html), or ConvertAvroToJson then [SplitJson](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.SplitJson/index.html). At that point you can use [EvaluateJsonPath](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.EvaluateJsonPath/index.html) to extract values into attributes (for use with [NiFi Expression Language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html)), and at some point you will likely want [ReplaceText](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ReplaceText/index.html) where you set the content of the flow file to a HiveQL statement (for use by SelectHiveQL).